# Ending question with "of"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I know that ending sentences with prepositions should be avoided, but still. Can I ask so:"What is the aileron part of?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon to which you refer is called preposition stranding where a preposition is not in its natural place. Despite what you may have read authorities disagree about whether it is always to be avoided. The [Wikipedia article on preposition stranding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) gives much detail about the controversy. It is alleged that the practice started with attempts to import practices from Latin into English

In the specific example you quote

> What is the aileron part of?

the option of

> Of what is the aileron part?

sounds rather contrived to me and your version is more natural.

Comment: Rephrasing the sentence is another option, for example: "Which [system, unit, device] [includes, contains] the aileron?"

Answer (score 2):

Ending a sentence with a preposition like 'of' is not a big issue in spoken or informal language. You should only be concerned if you are writing in a more formal context, which is unlikely in this case since the sentence is a question.

Comment: What would you say if you were me?

Answer (score 2):

> I know that ending sentences with prepositions should be avoided…

There is no such rule in English as actually practised by real English speakers and writers—not in informal speech, not in formal writing.

This so-called ‘rule’ against ‘[preposition stranding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding)’ is an artificial fabrication of confused grammarians of the 17th century, whose ideas of English were clouded by Latin envy.
Linguistic prescriptivists have carried the ‘rule’ on just to make themselves feel superior by imposing arbitrary rules on others and belittling their perfectly legitimate English usage.

*That is the sort of tedious nonsense up with which I will not put!*

Sometimes sentences may be *clumsier* with prepositions in different places, but in this case:

> Can I ask so: "What is the aileron part of?"

Absolutely yes!
This is perfectly natural to ask and there is no other reasonable way to rephrase it.
No native speaker of English would even be tempted to ask, ‘Of what is the aileron part?’; in fact, most would probably have to scan such awkward phrasing twice to figure out what it meant.